# Codeception run could not open input file

Tags: php, windows, laravel, codeception

When i run codeception with laravel on windows machine:

```
 [Codeception\Exception\TestParseException]
 Couldn't parse test 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\laravel\blog\tests\functional\\LoginCest.php'
 Could not open input file: C:\Program
```

Comment: can u share code please ?

Comment: wich code? this is basic codeception instalation, just run bootstrap created a cept and when i run again it gives me errors

Comment: Seems like that path is not being escaped correctly. Not that familiar with Codeception but I'd guess its configurable somewhere.

Comment: you're right i changed the project location and it's working, thx